# JavaFX With Connection To Firebase On Raspberry Pi System

Tags: java, linux, firebase, javafx, firebase-realtime-database

I am running JavaFX jar file on Windows system and my code includes connection to Firebase. I make the connection to the firebase through the following code:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Connecting FireBase...");

    // Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
    FirebaseOptions options = null;
        try {
        options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()      
 .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(getServiceAccount(<path-to-json-file>)))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://<firebase-name>.firebaseio.com")
            .build();
         } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
     } 

     FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
     System.out.println("Connecting to FireBase and initializing...");

    // check if the connection succedded
    DatabaseReference connectedRef = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
    connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
        if (connected) {
            System.out.println("Connected to firebase!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not connected to firebase...");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
    }
});

System.out.println("Get a reference to the firebase db...");
// Get a reference to our posts
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("server/<path>");

// rest of the code ...
}
```

Eventually, I get the following output:

> Connected to firebase!

Now I have to run the same jar file on Raspberry Pi system. When I execute the jar on Raspberry Pi, the console outputs the following:

> Not connected to firebase...

and there is no exceptions.

Is there any way to check what is the reason of no connection to firebase from Raspberry Pi system?
How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Does the RaspberryPi have access to the internet? And which JRE/JDK are you running in on both devices

Comment: Yes, the RPi has access to the internet. I can connect to my firebase db from the web browser on RPi system.

Comment: On my Windows system I run in jdk 1.8. On my RPi system I run in java-8-openjdk-armhf.

Comment: Can you run wireshark, see if there is traffic going, or just a reset?

Comment: I tried. Nothing happens. No messages coming out.

Comment: The problem is still valid ... Is there another idea please?

Comment: Are you using a local json path?

Comment: Yes, a local json path.

Comment: And the json file is on both machines in the exact same directory?

Comment: Yes... I even checked that the path is valid on RPi by printing the full path to see if it is OK.

Comment: Can you attach a debugger to the jar and what the state is when `Not connected to firebase...` is output